# Fuse-box - can't import ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, fusebox

I want to change packer for my side project from webpack to fuse-box.

Code is compiling with no problem but when I want to load it, I see an error:

[image]

I downloaded React demo code and it's working. Also on webpack there is no problem either.

Link to my repo:
https://github.com/slaby93/talkie-react-application/tree/fuse-box-react-dom-problem

Answer (score 0):

Please, submit an issue or join our gitter channel gitter.im/fusebox-bundler/Lobby we will help you.